# Site refused to connect while elastic ip is working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, elastic-ip

I setup an ec2 instance and configured elastic ip.

I can access my app via web browser through public dns given by ec2 vpc, and ip address given by elastic ip.

but when I try to use my custom domain(i did not use route 53 for this), it will refuse to connect.

I thought it was dns propagation issue but services like https://www.whatsmydns.net/ says my dns is propagated. it comes back with correct ip address and reachable for most countries.(but to be fair, it was about 8~ hours when I added ip addresse as A name record.)

what could be the issue here? since I can reach my app through ip address, I was thinking security group configuration was done correctly but I maybe wrong.

Can anyone guide me here?

Comment: what error do you get when you try domain instead of ip?

Comment: "this site can't be reached". "myapp refused to connect"

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did not get any answers.. I asked dns hosting guys, they said it looks fine on their end, and when I looked at aws, all looked fine..

so, instead of using elastic ip, I fixed it by using ELB - so probably name servers were needed to be provided to dns host...